# Select rows for a specific month in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 12 hourly data for over 10 years. All data are stored in date wise. I would like to extract columns containing the data from a specific month (note that month is not in standard 1, 2, 3, format). The rows of the 'date' column which I have looks like this:

```
01-May-07
02-May-07
.
.
.
31-Oct-17
```

How do I select only columns which contain data only for May, Jun etc.

Initially I thought that I can extract using `df[df['DATE'].str.contains('May')]`. But it did not work as expected resulting in output as input.

Edit 1

```
DATE    TIME    MOONPH  SPEED   GUST    CLOUD AMOUNT    DRY WET DEW RH
01-May-07   230 NM7 6   0   4   27.4    25.4    25.4    86
01-May-07   330 NM7 4   0   4   27.4    25.4    25.4    86
01-May-07   430 NM7 3   0   4   27.4    25.4    25.4    86
01-May-07   530 NM7 2   0   4   27.4    25.4    25.4    89
01-May-07   630 NM7 3   0   5   27.4    26  25.4    85
01-May-07   700 NM7 0   0   4   27.8    26  25.4    81
01-May-07   730 NM7 0   0   4   27.8    26  25.4    81
01-May-07   800 NM7 2   0   4   27.8    26  25.4    81
01-May-07   830 NM7 5   0   4   29.2    26  24.6    76
01-May-07   900 NM7 5   0   4   29.2    26  24.6    76
01-May-07   930 NM7 5   0   2   29.8    26  24.6    76
01-May-07   1000    NM7 5   0   4   30.8    26  24.6    76
01-May-07   1030    NM7 5   0   4   30.8    26  24.6    76
01-May-07   1100    NM7 6   0   4   31.4    26  24.6    68
.
.
.
01-May-17   1630    NM7 8   0   5   32.6    27.4    25.6    68
01-May-17   1930    NM7 8   0   5   32  27.4    25.6    69
01-May-17   430 NM7 0   0   5   27.2    25  24  83
01-May-17   30  NM7 0   0   5   29.6    27.2    26.2    82
01-May-17   530 NM7 0   0   5   26.6    24.4    23.4    83
01-May-17   130 NM7 0   0   5   28  25.6    24.6    82
01-May-17   630 NM7 0   0   5   26.8    24.4    23.3    81
01-May-17   730 NM7 0   0   5   27.2    24.4    23.4    80
01-May-17   330 NM7 0   0   5   27.2    25  24  83
01-May-17   1230    NM7 10  0   5   32.8    28.2    25.2    64
01-May-17   2330    NM7 4   0   4   30  26.4    24.9    75
01-May-17   2230    NM7 5   0   4   30  26.8    25.5    77
01-May-17   2130    NM7 4   0   4   30  26.8    25.5    77
01-May-17   830 NM7 2   0   5   27.2    24.4    23.4    78
01-May-17   930 NM7 3   0   5   31.2    27.2    25.6    72
01-May-17   1830    NM7 8   0   5   32  27.4    25.6    69
01-May-17   1130    NM7 6   0   5   32.8    28.2    25.2    64
01-May-17   2030    NM7 6   0   4   32  26.8    25.4    76
01-May-17   1330    NM7 10  0   5   33  27.6    25.4    64
01-May-17   1430    NM7 10  0   5   33  27.6    25.2    65
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think need convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then compare with [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) or [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and `%B` for [`month names`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['01-May-07', '02-May-07', '31-Oct-17']})
print (df)
        DATE
0  01-May-07
1  02-May-07
2  31-Oct-17
```

---

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.month == 5]
```

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.strftime('%B') == 'May']
```

---

```
print (df)
        DATE
0  01-May-07
1  02-May-07
```

If need working with datetimes later:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df = df[df['DATE'].dt.month == 5]
#df = df[df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%B') == 'May']
print (df)
        DATE
0 2007-05-01
1 2007-05-02
```

EDIT:

If dont need working with `datetimes`, for me with your data your approach working:

```
df = df[df['DATE'].str.contains('May')]
```

Comment: your last example resulted in error `ttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
`

Comment: @sundar_ima - Maybe you forget `df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])`

Comment: Before using `pd.to_datetime` command, there was 38310 rows. After your suggestion, it appears to be converting. But after filtering May, I get 35389 rows.

Comment: @sundar_ima - Are data confidental?

Comment: @sundar_ima - If possible, is possible filter only `datetime` column and share data? `df['DATE'].to_csv(file, index=False)` ?

Comment: @sundar_ima - It seems there are many `May`s rows, `35389 rows` should be expected.

Comment: @sundar_ima - One thing, what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: Opps your last debug print (df.index) tells me I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do. I would merge the Date and Time column with a space between them. Then keep the column name as DATE. The column will look something like this

```
   DATE    
01-May-07 230 
01-May-07 330 
01-May-07 430
```

......
Then I would covert the column to datetime object.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], formate = '%d-%b-%y %H%M')
```

Then set the DATE column as index

```
df = df.set_index('DATE')
```

Then when the dataframe become time series, then in many ways you can extract a portion of your data based on time. For instance if I only want data from January

```
jan_data = df['2007-Jan']
```

first week of May

```
may_1st_week = df['2007-May-01':'2007-May-07']
```

And so on.

Comment: to convert string to datetime object, I used this reference https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime#:~:text=We%20can%20convert%20a%20string,datetime%20and%20time%20objects%20respectively.